Adding Custom Drop down for specific columns in DT
I have a simple dashboard made in flexdashboard, this is the Rmd code:
```
---
title: "Dahboard"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(palmerpenguins)
df <- penguins
```

# Column {data-width=650}

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}

renderDT(df)
```

The result is a table of the penguins dataset. However, I need to perform some operations in the columns of the dataset, and I wanted to make my table interactive and editable.
Specifically, I would like to have a "weight" selector above each column containing numeric data, indicating by what weight the column values ​​should be multiplied, like in the following photo:

In this example, in fact, there is a weight selector for each single numeric column, which multiplies in real time all the values ​​of the column by the relative weight and updates the result in the column "Aggregate Index".
Is there a way to achieve a similar result using DT?
